# Custom Bokeh Legend for Bar Graph

Tags: python, dataframe, bar-chart, legend, bokeh

In bokeh, I created a Bar chart of genes vs some metric a (it doesn't matter what the y-value is), but I would like to color the bars by some metric b (again, doesn't matter). This is very doable by setting `color='b'` in the Bar constructor (assume b is a column in the dataframe that is the source for the bar chart). However, I cannot seem to find a way to get the legend to only show the colors vs the metric b value they represent. Does anyone know how to do this?